# How to Open a webpage for the user that uses the command

Tags: discord.net

I want to have a command, that when you type it in, it opens a link for the client, not sure how to do this.

Example: '/youtube' would open 'https://www.youtube.com/' for whoever used that command.

Comment: and where exactly would this command be typed?

Comment: In the Discord App chat box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This goes against Discord's policy, and it would never be added for security reasons.

**Think of it like this :** 
Would you like a bot having access to programs on your computer, and many other permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "open" as in "opens in the browser" or as in "link is shown in chat"?

Btw, I think that you shouldn't use "opens in the browser", because if the user wants to, he'll just open the link by himself.

Here is how to show a link in the chat:

```
        //command
        commands.CreateCommand("website")
            .Do(async e =>
            {
                await e.Channel.SendMessage("www.yourwebsite.com/"); //sending message
            });
```

Of course you need other things for this to work, f.e. a prefix-code block. I suggest you look up some tutorials (there are a bunch of them on YouTube) or docs.

Comment: I mean open as opens in the browser, I know how to do the link in chat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to open chrome on your desktop using discord. `os.system` lets you execute shell commands.

```
import os
os.system('chrome youtube.com')
```

You'll need to set the path to chrome.exe in Environment variables. This will allow cmd to run chrome from any directory.

Comment: This is a really old question, but I was asking how would I open the browser on the user's computer. So if you type the command, how could I open your browser. As unknown answered, you can't, discord doesn't allow it, as it would cause ***major*** security problems.